# AngularJS get length of specific item in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

Hey I have a JSON array that I'm calling from a service. I have some counters that I'd like to print out the length of the total array and length of some sub items. I'm able to print out the full length of the array but I also would like to print out the total number of items that have a progress "green", "red", and "yellow". Seeing that it's an array of objects, how would I go about to get the length of green, red, yellow?

JSON:

```
[
   {
     name: User1,
     progress: "green"
   },
   {
     name: User2,
     progress: "yellow"
   },
   {
     name: User3,
     progress: "green"
   },
    {
     name: User4,
     progress: "red"
   },
]
```

I'm storing the service called as so:

```
$scope.requestDetails = [];
$scope.requestDetails = data;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="total">{{requestDetails.length}}</div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Out of curiosity, I tried to print `{{requestDetails.progress.length}}` but it comes up empty and printing `{{requestDetails[0].progress.length}}` prints out the number of letters of the first object's progress value.

Comment: Look at using array filter method, which you can use to create a new array with only the progress values you want, then ask for the length of that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the angular built in filter:

```
{{requestDetails.lenght}}

{{(requestDetails | filter: {progress: 'red'}).length}}
```

You can also use a custom function on the controller for custom logic:

Controller code:

```
  $scope.colorFilter = function(color) {
    return function (obj) {
      return obj.progress === color;
    };
  };

{{(requestDetails | filter: colorFilter('red')).length}}
```

Note: since Angular 1.3 filters must declare their dependencies explicitly to create a `$watcher` on them, otherwise those parameters will not be dirty checked within the `$digest` cycle, and the output will not be affected by any 2-way bindings.

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zgzSqeMVnCQbpDitrSI3?p=preview

Comment: Nice! but this unfortunately spits out the 10 $digest() iterations reached...i'm still digging into it

Comment: if you can elaborate on how this array is populated and \ or changed, perhaps I can offer some further assistance

Comment: Of course! I'm looping thru this array using ng-repeat on a table element...I have 3 counters on top of the table that would display the # of total, green,red,and yellow records...I think using this filter coupled with the ng-repeat spits out the digest error

Comment: Hey Oleg, it's fixed now! in my controller where I was calling my service and storing the aforementioned data, I had two instances of the same "GET" call to get my data...I removed the duplicate and works like a charm...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your data in the controller, counting every element:

```
$scope.itemData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.requestDetails.length; ++i) {
  var detail = $scope.requestDetails[i];
  if ($scope.itemData[detail.progress] === undefined) {
    $scope.itemData[detail.progress] = 0;
  }
  $scope.itemData[detail.progress]++;
}
```

and use it in your template:

```
<div class="red">{{ itemData.red }}</div>
<div class="green">{{ itemData.green }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, the goal is to display counts of each progress type from the object?

If this is the case, here is one possible solution.

HTML

```
<div>{{requestDetails.length}}</div>
<div class="red">{{(requestDetails | filter: {progress: 'red'}).length}}</div>
<div class="green">{{(requestDetails | filter: {progress: 'green'}).length}}</div>
```

This method leverages the built in angular filter. For more reading on filters and angularjs, here are the [docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)